# how to set select value on the next page

Tags: html, django, select

i am confused here. i am trying to set the value of selected option to what i got from previous form submission.

my form:

```
...
<select name="city"><option>city</option>...
```

then after submit, i land on this page:

```
your selected criteria: 
<select name="city" value="{{city}}"><option>city</option>...
```

but i cannot do so, cos `select` doesnot have `value` option. how can i catch the value and set to select option?

thru js, it is bad option, i just want a real django-solution.

thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

```
<select>
{% for x in cities %}
  {% if x == city %}
        <option selected=selected>{{x}}</option>

   {% else %}
        <option>{{x}}</option>

  {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
</select>
```

Comment: how do i know if ``x`` is the selected value?

Comment: You would have to send the selected value from the previous page and pass it to the page where you want to show result. In my code, I have assumed that "city" is the passed value.

Comment: the problem is: i have only ONE option possible to select in previous page. so there is only ONE selectable out of 3. and i want to set THAT selected city back again in the next page. - i cannot use for loop

Comment: This is just an example. Any ways template is required to know what the selected value and you could have an if condition to test the values against the selected one and set the option tag to selected.